# Violation of Liskov Substitution Principle?

Tags: design, object-oriented

I've have an animal class

```
class Animal
{
    public function eat(Food $food);
}
```

the subclass who inherit it actually cannot support all kinds of Food (Cat can only eat meat):

```
class Cat extends Animal
{
    public function eat(Food $food)
    {
        if (!$food instanceof Meat) throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    }
}
```

of course, `Meat` is a subclass of `Food`

So is this code violate LSP (I think it does)? and how to re-design it?

====================================

PS. The description above is an edited version. the original version is like below:

I've defined a data transformer interface

```
interface TransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function transform($origin); 
}
```

As you could see, $origin and the return type could be any type of data (I use PHP), however, the class who implements it actually cannot support all kinds of data, (I think it should be OK if it returns certain type of data, it doesn't violate LSP):

```
class TagTransformer implements TransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($origin)
    {
        if (!is_string($origin)) throw new InvalidArgumentException();
        ...
    }
}
```

So is this code violate LSP (I think it does)? and how to re-design it?

Comment: What constraint do you think it violates?

Comment: 'TagTransformer' is a base class?

Comment: thanks for the reply, as the LSP is related to "inherit" so I think the example I listed is no good. I'll change the description with a more suitable example.

Comment: @chrisyue: [The LSP applies to interfaces and base classes, as per this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252363/does-liskov-substitution-principle-also-apply-to-classes-implementing-interfaces). There was no need to change your example to inheritance.

Comment: @Flater yes indeed, however there was no answer after eight hours and looks like confusing some people, I thought I need to ask in a more clear and acceptable way :). As I've modified the question while you answering, the answer may looks wired to new comers, so I am going to append the original content back.

Comment: As with every question about the LSP here, I need to point out that the LSP is about *the documented contract of a class*. There is no documented contract for your `eat` or `transform` method in your post. Is throwing an `InvalidArgumentException` an allowed action under the contract of the base class? If yes, it's not a violation, if no, it is a violation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170138/is-this-a-violation-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LSP:

> Let φ(x) be a property provable about objects x of type T. Then φ(y)
> should be true for objects y of type S where S is a subtype of T.

What is provable about `Animal`? You don't provide code or return type, presumably something like:

```
(Animal.Hungry = false AND Food.State = Consumed) OR InvalidArgumentException thrown
```

Is it still true for `Cat`? Yes (assuming you add the state changes).

Now what about `Food` and `Meat`? You don't prove any code, so we can assume the only difference is the Type. No violation is possible.

What about that type checking statement in `Cat` though? This looks bad, it's not a LSP violation, but it does raise questions about whether Food has a violation in it. If it doesn't, then I shouldn't need to check the Type right?

Really, the code smell is pointing out that `Food` should have some sort of `FoodType` property or `CanBeEatenBy(Animal animal)` method, rather than using SubTypes to identify the type.

**Edit: it seems the correct design is in scope...**

I'm going to use C#, which has a "flaw" in that you can't specify what exceptions might be thrown in the class definition. That being the case, and respecting the normal rule about not using exceptions for logic, I will try to avoid all exceptions.

Obviously, this isn't the only way to do this, it's just a way to avoid your code smell and problems with exceptions.

```cs
public enum AnimalType
{
    Omnivore,
    Herbivore,
    Carnivore
}

public class Food
{
    public bool IsEdibleBy(Animal a)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class EatenFood
{
    public override bool IsEdibleBy(Animal a)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class Animal
{
    public readonly AnimalType Type = AnimalType.Omnivore;
    public Food Eat(Food f)
    {
         if(f.IsEdibleBy(this))
         {
              return new EatenFood(f);
         }
         else
         {
              return f;
         }
    }
}
```

What is provable?

```
Eat always returns a type of Food 
IsEdibleBy always returns true or false
AnimalType is one of the enum values
```

Now we add Cat:

```cs
public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat() { this.Type = AnimalType.Carnivore; }
}

Public class Meat : Food
{
   public override bool IsEdibleBy(Animal a)
   {
       return a.Type == AnimalType.Omnivore || 
              a.Type == AnimalType.Carnivore;
   }
}
```

Now you have avoided all exceptions and LSP questions, you can extend your food types indefinitely, although you may have issues if you add more AnimalType enums. It would be important to make sure that that list is complete at the start.

Comment: Note that in OP's example, your quote of the LSP does fail. Provable property "cat eats food" is violated for Meat, which is a subtype of Food.

Comment: @Flater I include the possibly of the invalidarg exception in the provable statement for animal to avoid this violation.  The problem of course with exceptions is that in fact there is a massive list of technically possible exceptions for any function and that "does it terminate?" is... hard to prove

Comment: @Ewan as you are the only answerer who answers the second question with details, I decide to mark your answer as the right answer :)

Answer (score 8):

> **Note**
>   By the time I wrote my answer, you had changed your example from an interface implementation to a base class inheritance. My answer is still correct; since the LSP applies to interfaces and base classes [as per this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252363/does-liskov-substitution-principle-also-apply-to-classes-implementing-interfaces).
>
> You did change more in the example than just inheritance/interface, which does influence the answer. I've addressed this at the bottom of this answer.

This is not a violation of the LSP.

It would be a violation if the method is wholly unusable, i.e. you're not supposed to ever call the method `TagTransformer.transform`.

---

**Examples of the difference.**

*Excuse the C# syntax, it's been a while since I did PHP.*

```
public interface ICalculation
{
    void SetFirstNumber(int num);
    void SetSecondNumber(int num);
    int CalculateOutputFromNumbers();
}
```

Implementation 1:

```
public class Addition : ICalculation
{
    public void SetFirstNumber(int num)
    {
        this.Number1 = num;
    }

    public void SetSecondNumber(int num)
    {
        this.Number2 = num;
    }

    public int CalculateOutputFromNumbers()
    {
        return this.Number1 + this.Number2;
    }
}
```

This is clearly using the interface as intended. No issue here.

Implementation 2:

```
public class SquareRoot: ICalculation
{
    public void SetFirstNumber(int num)
    {
        this.Number1 = num;
    }

    public void SetSecondNumber(int num)
    {
        throw new Exception("Square roots only take one input value!);
    }

    public int CalculateOutputFromNumbers()
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(this.Number1);
    }
}
```

Notice how you're **never** going to be allowed to call the `SetSecondNumber` method from `SquareRoot`, even though the method is part of the `ICalculation` interface and `SquareRoot` implements `ICalculation`.

This violates LSP. In order to calculate a square root, `SquareRoot` class needs to be treated differently from other `ICalculation`-implementing classes.

Implementation 3:

```
public class Division : ICalculation
{
    public void SetFirstNumber(int num)
    {
        this.Number1 = num;
    }

    public void SetSecondNumber(int num)
    {
        if(num == 0)
            throw new Exception("You can't divide by zero!"); 

        this.Number2 = num;
    }

    public int CalculateOutputFromNumbers()
    {
        return this.Number1 / this.Number2;
    }
}
```

Based on your question, it seems that you think this is a violation of LSP. This is essentially what's happening in your code example, a specific exception is being thrown for a given invalid value.

This is not a violation. Notice how you're **allowed** to call the `SetSecondNumber` method from `Division`, but you simply can't use an impossible value (0).

This isn't a matter of having to use the `Division` class differently from `ICalculation`-implementing classes; it's simply a matter of **bad input, no possible output**.

That is significantly different from the `SquareRoot` example; at least in relation to LSP.

---

**In response to your new example**

Your new example does in a way invalidate your original question.

Your old example was a PHP snippet:

```
public function transform($origin)
{
    if (!is_string($origin)) throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    ...
}
```

It's important to note here that **there is no type constraint on `$origin`**. This means that checking for a usable type is a logical consequence, and not inherently bad design (since the language allows for untyped parameters).

However, this is significantly different in your revised example:

```
public function eat(Food $food)
{
    if ($food instanceof Meat) throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    ...
}
```

It's important to note here that **there is a type constraint on `$food`**. 
You're no longer using a typeless parameter. You're specifying that the parameter is of type `Food`.

At this point, it becomes an LSP violation. Your input validation is no longer a matter of how the language works; but rather a consequence of the contract that is specified by your `Animal` base class.

You're trying to create a `Cat` which inherits from `Animal` but actually (partially) outright refuses to implement `Eat(Food)`. That is a willful exclusion of functionality, which does make it an LSP violation.

*I would consider this **an LSP violation of `Meat`/`Food`**, more than it is an LSP violation of `Cat`/`Animal`. Meat is clearly being treated differently from Food, which violates the contract that says that Meat is a Food.*

Comment: I think both your and the question's examples are LSP violations _if_ it is not part of the interface contract that invalid arguments throw in that way. If `eat` is defined as "Instance eats the specified food or throws InvalidArgumentException if it's incompatible" then we're good. If it's merely "Instance eats the specified food" then we're not good, but also the `Animal` interface was poorly designed.

Comment: @Phoshi: I was already drafting an update to the updated example (see my answer now). The difference is that in OP's initial example, the exception was related to the language used (which allows typeless parameters - thus opening the door to unexpected types being passed - thus making it acceptable to throw on unusable types, in my opinion). However, in the revised example, he's now working with a typed parameter (which in and of itself displays inheritance on top of that), which does significantly change the violation here. I hope you agree with my updated answer.

Comment: @Phoshi: Maybe a better reply after re-reading your comment: Regardless of the contract definition, if no meaningful result can be achieved; then an exception is the only reasonable outcome. LSP or not, if there's no other option than throwing an exception, throwing an exception can't be wrong or in violation of anything.

Comment: I think the origin example also break the LSP because the original contract `TransformerInterface::transform` is considered to handle "everything", like PHP's `var_dump` function. However the `TagTransformer::transform` only can handle "string". which should be more appropriate as `TagTransformer::transform(string $origin)`. no matter there's typehint or not, I always fell it's a code smell of type checking for parameters, no matter it's "typeof" or "is_xxx"

Comment: @chrisyue: Those are valid concerns (I don't like untyped parameters for exactly this reason), but that's not really what LSP is about. Having to type check is a logical consequence of not enforcing a type to begin with. If you don't like type checking, then enforce a type. Problem solved. Type checking of typed variables (e.g. `Base b = new Derived(); if(b is Derived) { HandleDerived(d); }`) is more often than not an **abuse** of polymorphism; and I suggest avoiding this altogether to prevent future code smells and LSP violations.

Comment: @Flater: Type checking *period* is abuse. Not of polymorphism, but of inheritance. It's actually a *disuse* of polymorphism, as you're no longer relying on your object to do the right thing unless it's of some specific type. Absent a type declaration, I should be able to pass a `Url` in place of a string and have it work.

Comment: @cHao: I consider it an abuse of polymorphism as (in my earlier example) the variable is needlessly declared as type `Base`, which you're only allowed to do because of polymorphism. In pretty much every case I've seen, the developer has a valid reason to want to know the specific type later on; but he has already shot himself in the foot by unnecessarily downcasting the type at an earlier stage. To me, that means the issue is located in the earlier stage.

Comment: @Flater: Inheritance is what lets you declare a Derived as a Base. Polymorphism is what lets you call `ohj.do_something()` and have `obj` (or rather, in most languages, its class) decide what exactly that means. Strict static typing has shackled the two together for so long that the confusion is understandable. But only when you let the object itself direct things, and aren't concerned with what specific type you're given, are you using polymorphism.

Comment: @Flater As Ewan has answered the second question in details and the solution did enlighten me, so I decide to mark Ewan's answer as the right one. Still, thanks for the excellent answer, it helps me a lot and surely it will help more :)

Comment: @Flater I think there's more nuance to it than that. If I have some `IFoo.Bar(int frob)` which is not defined to ever throw, then throwing _is_ an LSP violation. If this means your implementation of `IFoo` cannot adhere to the contract, then the contract was poorly designed, but that doesn't make violating it any less an LSP violation. More reasonably, if it's defined to only throw `FooException` or `ArgumentException`, then throwing another exception type is an LSP violation. Exceptions are just as much a part of the interface as everything else and are violated in the same way.

Comment: @Phoshi: What you're mentioning is a violation of your own documentation (which would in that case contradict the actual behavior); it is not a LSP violation. Documentation that contradicts the actual behavior is always an issue (as it invalidates the documentation), regardless of what it's about. That's not an LSP issue. There is no way to define (on a technical level) what exception can possibly be thrown from a given method. Listing the exceptions (and the circumstances of them being thrown) is purely documentative.

Comment: @Flater IMO that's a very restrictive definition of LSP. Ignoring languages like java where it is possible (caveats apply) to define on a technical level which exceptions can be thrown, LSP *must* go deeper than merely what types are part of the signature. That part is checked by your compiler most of the time--LSP is about strong behavioural subtyping. If I have some type `Summer { int sum(int a, int b) }`  then what LSP is stating is you should be able to swap this to any subtype of `Summer` and "without altering any of the desirable properties of the program".

Comment: @Flater so if you have `WrongSummer` which always returns 4, swapping the types out changes the desirable properties of your program, i.e., it no longer works. Exactly the same with throwing something unexpected, your program no longer works, and thus you have violated a strong behavioural subtyping constraint by changing the behaviour in your subtype.

Comment: @Phoshi: LSP has nothing to do with the correctness of the value that is returned. Having a derived method that returns a fixed number is perfectly fine if returning the fixed number is correct for the class in which it is implemented (mocking is _the_ prime example here). What you're focusing on is the **context** (i.e. "this class says it sums two numbers") that is wrong compared to the actual behavior (always returning 4 and ignoring the input) which is not the focus of LSP. Your issue is of a documentative nature. [..]

Comment: @Phoshi: [..] If that class was called `Flooper` because it floops (= custom calculation that I've invented), your point would no longer stand since you don't know what flooping is and can't inherently label the output as wrong or right. That proves the point that you're focusing on a contextual/documentative issue, not a technical one.

Comment: @Phoshi: LSP is not a catchall principle for all inheritance abuse. It very specifically focuses on the fact that **when a `Foo` class implements a method that should never be called (or whose usage changes to a point of serving an entirely different purpose), then the interface/base class that requires its usage should not be used as part of the `Foo` class**. In other words, never implement required methods that you then expressly want to never be used (or use in a way they were never intended to be used).

Comment: @Flater I think it might be useful to go back to Barbara Liskov's own definition here, because I don't think either of us will word it better: "Let Φ(x) be a property provable about objects x of type T. Then Φ(y) should be true for objects y of type S where S is a subtype of T.". I'm not sure what property you are describing, but it is not the strong behavioural subtyping that Barbara defines for the LSP. For our `Summer`, that `sum(2, 3) = 5` is a property provable, and thus any subtype must also have that property provable. IMO her words are very clear here, LSP is extremely restrictive.

Comment: @Flater To map our example precisely onto the author of LSP's definition, let `x` be an instance of `Summer` and y be an instance of `WrongSummer` and `Φ(f)` be the property `f.sum(2, 3) == 5`. `Φ(x)` is true, because `Summer.sum(2, 3) == 5`. `Φ(y)` is false, because `WrongSummer.sum(2, 3) != 5`. This isn't about documentation or interfaces or any of that, it's more basic and restrictive than that. LSP is about *behaviour*, and *behaviour* covers everything--technically right down to bugs in the original implementation.

Comment: @Flater The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) page has some fairly decent additional definitions--note especially the links off to design-by-contract concepts and references to the definitions of behavioural subtyping

Comment: @Phoshi `that sum(2, 3) = 5 is a property provable, and thus any subtype must also have that property provable.` If every derived method was required to do or return the exact same thing, there would never be a point to override a method as the only purpose of overriding is to change its (base) method body. The issue with Liskov's examples is that she uses clearly defined mathematical constructs (a sum is rigidly defined), but in business logic such rigidity in definitions is more often absent than present; the existence of a derivation tends to imply that different behavior is needed.

Comment: @Flater "Liskov was describing something not useful for programming in business" is a criticism of LSP, but does not cause the definition to change. IMO it is entirely fair to say that violating LSP is desirable for your use case... but it doesn't change what it is.

Answer (score 2):

If it is documented that not every type of object is suitable for every subclass/implementation -- and that passing an unsuitable argument may result in an `InvalidArgumentException` -- then you're semi-OK. You've introduced this restriction in the superclass/interface, so you're not breaking the rules by enforcing it in subclasses. You're forcing a DIP violation on the caller, but you've basically satisfied LSP.

Otherwise, the fact that `$animal->eat($broccoli)` may break, and you can't know that without knowing about the subtype, means you're violating LSP. Methods succeed by default. (Exceptions are called "exceptions" for a reason.) So a declaration of `eat` sans failure conditions is a promise that `$animal->eat($food)` will at least succeed. `Cat` is unpromising that.

One way to resolve both issues is to provide a `can_eat` method on `Animal`, and declaring that if `$animal->can_eat($food)` is false, then `$animal->eat($food)` will (probably) fail.

Comment: What does DIP stand for?

Comment: The Dependency Inversion Principle. (It's the "D" in SOLID. LSP is the "L".) Abstracted out (cause lol), it means that you shouldn't depend on details, but on abstractions. It's the principle behind "programming to the interface". (In the example, the caller has to care about the specifics of the Animal and Food it has, which makes things more fragile.)

Answer (score 1):

The animal example is a violation which can be fixed easily. Do not mention food in the base class, make it so:
abstract Animal -> abstract Eater -> astract MeatEater -> Cat

The transformer example is OK. It is obvious that any particular transformer will not be able to transform anything into anything else, it merely states it can transform something into something else, that it features a (polymorph) Transform method.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function:

```
Makehappy(animal)
    Shop.buy(cream cake)
    animal.eat(cream cake)
```

And to my surprise,
Makehappy(cat)
Throws an exception.

The problem is: The contract for animal wasn’t stated correctly. The contract said wrongly: When you call animal.eat(food), the animal eats the food. Correct: when you call animal.eat(food), the animal either eats the food, or throws an exception. Better: The exception can tell you whether the food can still be given to another animal or not.